# Let $U = {\{p \in P_4(F) : p(2) =p (5) }\}$ . Find a basis for U.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U = {\{p \in P_4(F) : p(2) = p(5) }\}$ . Find a basis for U.

attempt: Let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ax^2 + ...+ a_4x^4 \in U.$
And let $p(2) =p(5). $

So simplifying after substitution we have that $1,(-21x + x^2),...,(-609x + x^4)$ is a basis of U.

(b) Find a subspace of $W$ of $P_4(F)$ such that $P_4(F) = U \oplus W$.

I know by definition since $P_4(F)$ is finite dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $P_4(F)$ then there is a  subspace $W$ such that $P_4(F) = U \oplus W$. But I don't know how to define it.

Can someone please check this and help?Thank you!

Comment: *Hint:* What is the dimension of $W$ if $P_4(F) = U \oplus W$ ?

Comment: It will be less than or equal to the dimension of $P_4(F)$?

Comment: Can someone please give me some feedback?